# After burping saying "Stück Brot dazu?"

Tags: etymology, meaning-in-context, idiom

When someone burps loudly, why is it a custom to ask **"Stück Brot dazu?"**?

I came across this in [this article](https://www.faz.net/aktuell/feuilleton/medien/suche-drecksau-fuers-leben-cora-schumachers-house-of-love-16919005.html):

> Einer rülpst laut, sie ruft ihm jovial zu: „Stück Brot dazu?“ Voll
> Sympathie zwinkern die beiden sich zu. Romantisch, wie sich hier das
> Herz zum Herzen findet.

Comment: Please note that this seems only to be custom in some parts of Germany. I'm a native speaker and I have never heard it.

Comment: @Closevoters: This seems a legit question about etymology and also about the literal and idiomatical meaning of this phrase to me. Where in the Germanophonic area it is common and where not could also be part of the etymological section of the answer.

Comment: Is it a *custom*, or is it rather a somewhat commonly repeated *joke* among some people?

Comment: My *guess* is, that when eating soup, a sausage, etc., it is customary to ask, if you'd like some bread. After a burp it is common to say "Mahlzeit", as it often follows after eating a lot. To me, asking "Stück Brot dazu" just takes this a step further. Bottom line: It's a joking way to acknowledge your burp.

Comment: https://www.mundmische.de/bedeutung/13653-Ein_Stueck_Brot_dazu

Comment: I am familiar with that phrase in the context of sneezing / coughing. My guess would be that it stems from the fact that you usually serve bread with something liquid like soup. So if sneeze / wet cough there's body fluids, ... you can imagine the rest. It should be obvious but the custom is rather rude imo.

Comment: @HPB: other comments suggest that this might be regional. Can you please add the area or "peer group" where you hear this often?

Comment: As @idkfa said, I also know the saying after sneezing 'very wet', and if I remember correctly it's a "Scheibe Brot dazu ?". Possibly a cultural reference to a movie, comic strip or some such ... But it is not very common, to my knowledge and as has been said, I'd rather not use in cases where I'd like to be polite.

Comment: »Tschuldigung. Ich wollte ein Lied singen, aber hab den Text vergessen.«

Answer (score 7):

As a native speaker, I have not heared this phrase often, but similar phrases in similar contexts.

In Germany, as in many other countries, it's considered rude to burp loudly. And obviously, you dont get your head chopped off when you do. But its a usual thing to address the rudeness of others with some form of "jovial", yet criticizing remark. Mostly just jokingly criticizing, even though you dont mind the behaviour, but you know its considered rude.

Some examples would be, when you sneeze loudly, some people might yell out "aufwischen!" (to mop up), as if to say, "you sneezed so damn hard you left a puddle".

When people stare with their mouth open, a common remark is to say something along the lines of "mach den mund zu es zieht" (close your mouth, you're creating a draft).

When people had their pants zipper open, people would look them in the eye and just, seemingly randomly, start counting. Everybody understood what that meant. It was kind of an inside joke. The zipper on ones pants is referred to as the "cows barn" and counting would mean "counting down how many cows are escaping", as the "barn is open".

In todays use of my mothers tounge, Aramaic, we have a phrase when someone sneezes really loud. Which roughly translates to "Damn, you woke the dead!"

Now, with the "Stück brot dazu", its a similar remark, but its explanation is a little more disgusting. Bread is served as an addition to many dishes in many different cultures. And in restaurants you can ask for extra bread to your meal. The person making the exaggerated remark jokingly suggests that some of your meal might have come up with that burp and its so massive that it itself counts as a meal. Or that you "re-eat" your food. Therefor they ask you, if you'd like to have some bread to enjoy your "newly created" meal.

Its a friendly little jab, usually not taken as a serious remark but rather playful banter. A sort of inside joke or hyperbole of the other persons behaviour.

Comment: "Stück Brot dazu" is also used as a comment to other "body sounds" See [here](https://www.mundmische.de/bedeutung/13653-Ein_Stueck_Brot_dazu) or [here](https://www.mundmische.de/bedeutung/20227-Stueck_Brot_dazu). Also "Mahlzeit" is used as a comment to a burp.

Answer (score 0):

I have never heard it but its obviously just to comfort him/her in that context and not make them feel embarrassed. I guess saying it in a harsher voice would have a meaning like:
Oh come on stop that...